# How to install 6.0.1OTA update on a rooted nexus 5

Tags: rooting, ota-update, unrooting

My Nexus 5 is rooted. I received the 6.0.1 OTA update but when I try to install the update (I just clicked install link when the update finished downloading), the device restarts and goes to the [TWRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:TWRP_2.7.0.0.png) screen and doesn't install the update.

Can anyone tell me how I can get the update to install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot install an OTA update on rooted device because SuperSU changes some statement in install-recovery.sh to run itself on boot.

To install OTA you need to install factory image available at https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en

If you dont want to loose your apps and data. Simply edit the script **flash-all.bat** and remove

```
-w
```

From

```
fastboot -w update image-hammerhead-*.zip
```

Installation script file name will differ according to your OS.

You will loose root access and TWRP after going through above method as there's no other way to install OTA because all system files should be intact for successful installation of OTA.

Comment: If that SH file is the issue here, shouldn't removing SuperSU followed by reverting that file back to its original state help here? Also, have you read about [block based OTA's](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/block.html)

Comment: @Firelord I came to know about this when i tried to install an OTA update zip by flashing manually using stock recovery when my device was rooted. Where the stock recovery stated that it has some directory issues in install-recovery.sh . Then i went through this file which stated that SuperSU will launch in daemon mode on boot. By default this file contains the block information for applying OTA patch. This is file is located at  **/system/etc/install-recovery.sh** . Instead of reverting everything i chose to flash system.img lazyy me.

Comment: Flashed 6.0.1 factory image successfully

Answer (score 1):

If your phone is rooted by flashing normal SuperSu, then the SuperSu app and binaries would have been pushed into the /system partition of your phone. OTAs normally verify the checksum of your current system partition with that of untouched stock system partition's before the update. By rooting your device, which modifies the system, the MD5 sum would definitely not match, so you won't be able to install the OTA.

If you had rooted it by using systemless root (by SuperSu), then you can flash the OTA with no issues, since system partition will not be modified by that method. It seems you have TWRP installed now. It is better to flash the [stock ROM (6.0)](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en) and don't root it. Then install the (6.0.1) OTA through the stock recovery.

There's no way other than this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a special reason not to flash  6.0.1 directly?

Comment: Hey, 6.0.1 is just a minimal update with bug fixes & security patches for 6.0, something like 30MB or whatever.

Comment: Can you support your statement "*OTAs normally verify the MD5 checksum of your current system partition with that of untouched stock system partition's before the update*" with a legit technical source? I need to see something. // The [default](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/verity.txt) appears to be [SHA256](http://nelenkov.blogspot.in/2014/05/using-kitkat-verified-boot.html).

Comment: I wasn't sure what checksum it was.. Just removed the MD5 part

Answer (score 0):

You can using app: [root] FlashFire that can downloaded in PlayStore.

Then, download the latest factory images package for Nexus 5 from [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images)

After the file is downloaded and saved in your phone, open FlashFire app.
The app will grant root access and if it found update[OTA] file, choose 'delete'.

Next, click "plus" icon > choose "Flash firmware package" > browse to the location that you saved the downloaded factory image.

Then the app will scanning the firmware file and after that you can select some options.

*If you want to keep TWRP as recovery, just uncheck "Recovery".

*Be careful, if you want to keep your data in phone, make sure that "Data" unchecked.

Last, just click "FLASH" then your phone will reboot and install the update.

*Note: I've tried this for my Nexus 5 and it is successfull. Hope it works for you too :)